# Minify Angular 2 rc1

Tags: angular, bundling-and-minification

I'm developing a django web app using Angular 2. With the new Angular 2 RC1 (I was using beta) now my app loading looks like this:

[image]

322 requests just to load a simple list

Since I'm developing with django test server, performances are not great, so it takes 16 seconds (or more) to satisfy all the requests.

I'm not an Angular expert, so I'm here asking: is there a way to unify/minify/uglify all these JavaScript files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this comment in the Angular issue log, I think you'll need to wait for them to release bundles at some point:

http://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8412#issuecomment-216469197

> "we're not yet shipping bundles with the new RC (soon)"

Comment: The comment point to github project ( https://github.com/robwormald/new-world-test/blob/system/system-js/bundle.js ) with an example demonstrating how to bundle it. Thank you for the hint!